Movie about a boy who had autism and his father was moving his family out
Me and my brother watched a movie a couple years ago. It was about a boy who had autism and his father was moving his family out.
He had a wife who wasn't the boy's mother and she had a daughter. They were moving out to the woods the boy was very smart in ways not normal. The sister called him weird and was just mean. So while they were moving things in I can't remember but I believe the dad moved because he stole money. 
So the men came to find him and get the money. I think they killed the mom and dad. So the boy is smart and he opens the window like he left and put razors in the window seal so when the man looked over the edge they go through his hand. 
Then either swallows or puts a razor in his mouth. Later on I can't remember but the men were looking for the kids. The boys uses the sisters hair pin to get into a car place and they rob a car but the people show up. 
Later on when the kids return to the house I assume to find the money and while shooting they find it inside the mattress the reason it was so heavy. in the end the kids get revenge and kills the man in a work spot trailer.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Thank you for the detailed plot description. Marking this as a duplicate since this movie comes up a lot in ID.
